# Window closes immediatelly after run

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyuic

My code calls one window with a button. When the button is clicked, call another window. But the second window closes immediately

"basic" and "windows_two" are .py libraries genereted by pyuic5 from .ui files

```
import basic, windows_two
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    #Declarations
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    def Call_Second_Window():
        #Second Screen
        Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = windows_two.Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(Form)
        Form.show()
        
    def Call_Main_Window():
        #MainWindow
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = basic.Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)      
        ui.printButton.clicked.connect(Call_Second_Window) #click event to second window
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
    
    Call_Main_Window()
```

Whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a variable is *local* it gets "garbage collected" as soon as the function returns; this means that everything the variable might reference to will also be (possibly) deleted too.

What is happening in your case is that while the windows is correctly created, it will be immediately deleted (due to the garbage collection) when the `Call_Second_Window` returns (just after `Form.show()`).

To avoid that there is only one solution: make the reference to the object persistent. There are various approaches to achieve that, depending on the situation.

Unfortunately your code is a bit unorthodox (especially from a PyQt perspective), so I'm "refactoring" it in order to make it more standardized, better object oriented and, also importantly, easily readable.

```
import basic, windows_two
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = basic.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.printButton.clicked.connect(self.call_Second_Window) 

        self.secondWindow = None

    def call_Second_Window(self):
        if not self.secondWindow:
            self.secondWindow = SecondWindow()
        self.secondWindow.show()


class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = windows_two.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sub>Note: As you can see, I changed the name of `call_Second_Window` with a lower "c", and that's because capitalized names should only be used for classes and constants, while function names should always start with a lower case. This is again for readability, which is very important in programming and one of the core principles of python. Read more about this and other important topics on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).</sub>

Comment: This solve the problem. I'm starting in python and make some mistakes sometimes... I'll study this code. Thank you very much!!!